# Spring MVC - Localisation - javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'welcome_page.title' for locale 'en'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I did scan through similar posts of properties file not being found and Spring MVC throwing the below error.

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'welcome_page.title' for locale 'en'.
```

Below is the ResourceBundle definition. Earlier, I had just used classpath:messages, but based on comments here, I changed it to WEB-INF/classes/messages

```
<beans:bean id="localisedMessages"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/classes/messages" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</beans:bean>
```

I double checked and found out that in the WAR file (which is made by STC) the property files messages.properties and messages_ml.properties file are present in WEB-INF/classes folder.

What more needs to be done here? I have put debug statements in the controller class which gets called, and the debug statements are visible. So looks like the controller is also getting invoked.

Comment: How can I do a real clean build? I don't know if cached files/or older versions of the generated class files are causing any problem.

Comment: One more thing I observed. The log statement I have put on the method inside the controller class is getting executed twice. The controller does not get extended from any class, and I am using just the plan `logger.debug` statement.